# While writing a test using dapptools, how do I send a transaction as a specific wallet address?

Tags: solidity, nft, testing, hardhat, dapptools

I'm playing around with dapptools: [dapp](https://github.com/dapphub/dapptools/tree/master/src/dapp)

And I want to write a test that checks the gas for OpenZeppelin's ERC721 implementation of the `transferFrom(..)` function.

Here's my test:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

import "ds-test/test.sol";

import "./DemoErc721.sol";

contract DemoErc721Test is DSTest {

    DemoErc721 a;
    address testWallet = address(0x7E67aF7FF72cb87b7B0100cA8128F4673D185234);
    address testWallet2 = address(0x7E67af7FF72Cb87B7b0100ca8128f4673D185235);

    function setUp() public {
        a = new DemoErc721();
    }

    function mintMultiple(uint256 numToMint) public {
        a.mint(testWallet, numToMint);
        assertEq(a.balanceOf(testWallet), numToMint);
    }

    function testMint_1() public {
        mintMultiple(1);
    }
    function testMint_2() public {
        mintMultiple(2);
    }
    function testMint_3() public {
        mintMultiple(3);
    }
    function testMint_4() public {
        mintMultiple(4);
    }
    function testMint_5() public {
        mintMultiple(5);
    }

    function testTransfer() public {
        mintMultiple(1);
        a.transferFrom(testWallet, testWallet2, 1);
    }
}
```

You can see that in the `mintMultiple` function, we are always minting tokens to the `testWallet` address.

So in the final test, `testTransfer()`, I expect to be able to transfer from `testWallet` to another wallet, because `testWallet` is the owner of NFT with tokenId `1`.

However, I think the way I've written this test causes the calling address to be this test contract's address, rather than the `testWallet` address.

The analogous logic in Hardhat would be something like [this](https://hardhat.org/guides/waffle-testing.html#testing-from-a-different-account):

> Finally, to execute a contract's method from another account, all you need to do is connect the Contract with the method being executed:

> `await greeter.connect(addr1).setGreeting("Hallo, Erde!");`

So my question is, how can I simulate making the `transferFrom` function call from `testWallet`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [@transmissions11 on twitter](https://twitter.com/transmissions11/status/1481655717404626953?s=20):

> you can't - can either create a testing User contract or use Foundry which has a .prank() cheatcode for this
>
> https://github.com/gakonst/foundry

Answer (score 0):

You can create another contract called, let's say, `TokenUser`. Initialise it with a token instance in the constructor. Now, define the calls the user can make to the token and write a wrapper function around it. Something like this

```js
contract TokenUser{

    Token  token;

    constructor(Token token_) public {
        token = token_;
    }

    function doTransfer(address to, uint amount) public returns (bool){
        return token.transfer(to, amount);
    }
    
    ...

    //other functions

}
```

Now in the `setUp()` in the test contract, create an instance of the token and pass the address to the user.

```
contract TokenTest is DSTest{

    Token token;
    TokenUser user1;
    TokenUser user2;

    function setUp() public {
       token = new Token("[required_inputs]");
       user1 = new TokenUser(token);
       user2 = new TokenUser(token);
    }

    // rest of the contract
    
}
```

For test functions, you can use the user instances

```js
function testSomething() public {
    user1.transfer(address(user2),100);
    user2.approve(address(user1),100);
}
```

This method can be used to simulate sending transactions from different accounts (the accounts being different TokenUser contracts). There is an elegant implementation example by dapphub, you can find it [here](https://github.com/dapphub/ds-token/blob/master/src/token.t.sol).